# aws - is there any cicd tools for uploading server code to ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I am hosting the server in Ec2 instance using docker container

Every time I want to deploy new version of server code, I have to do the followings:

```
1. use filezilla to sftp source code from local to ec2 instance
2. ssh -i server.pem ec2-user@ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
3. run docker-compose down to stop the container
4. sudo tar -zxvf my-server.tgz -C server.
5. run docker-compose up -d to start the container again
```

I'm just wondering if there are any ways to automate these steps using some CICD tool

Comment: Have you looked at CodeDeploy?